# Comparing input type date with current date

Tags: javascript, date

```
<input type="date" name="bday" id="biday" required>
```

I have to take the date from input type date field from the user and if the entered date is greater than the current date i have to print some error in the alert box. I Have tried various methods but none of them worked for input type date. I tried to take two variables one which stores the current date and the second which takes the value of date input element `

```
var startDate = Date(document.getElementByID('biday').value);
    var today = new Date();
    if (startDate > today) {
        alert("The first date is after the second date!");
```

`.Can someone please help me the procedure to get the task done.

Comment: Show us some of your approaches, otherwise we will not be able to help you

Comment: startDate.getTime() > new Date().getTime()

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk added my approach.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for suggestion but i tried and that's not working any other approach?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are number of errors on your code like `getElementByID` should be `getElementById` and you are not taking the `value` from input and so on. Check below snippet for reference.

```js
function checkDate() {

  var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('biday').value);
  var today = new Date();
  if (startDate.getTime() > today.getTime()) {
    alert("The first date is after the second date!");
  }  
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="bday" id="biday" required>
<input type="submit" value="check" onclick="checkDate()">
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realized value was missing. Thanks it worked.

Comment: The value returned from a Date input will be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. That will be parsed by the built-in parser as UTC, which is likely not what the OP expects. For users west of Greenwich, `startDate.getTime() > today.getTime()` will frequently be true even where *startDate* is "today".

Answer (score 1):

Here is the another way.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="date" id="dval" value="" />
 <button onclick="test()">TEsting</button>
```

**JS**

```
 function test() {
     var q = new Date();
     var date = new Date(q.getFullYear(),q.getMonth(),q.getDate());
     var mydate = new Date(document.getElementById('dval').value);

     if(date > mydate) {
        alert("Current Date is Greater THan the User Date");
     } else {
        alert("Current Date is Less than the User Date");
     }
  }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/bxa282ty/5/)

**Note:** `type="date"` is not supported in Firefox, or Internet Explorer 11 and earlier versions.

Comment: If the intention of creating *date* from *q* is just to zero the time, then `q.setHours(0,0,0,0)` will do. But *mydate* will be based on UTC so will be different by the user's timezone offset, resulting in unexpected behaviour for users west of Greenwich.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a little typo at `getElementByID` it should be `getElementById`

Also it is possible to compare date strings as the MYSQL Format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` so you could actually compare two values directly as a string.

```
 '2017-12-1' < '2017-12-3'
 // true
```

If you are operating with another format you can either create a new Date Object and parse it to a TimeStamp like following:

```
// Receives a date String or Object
// and returns the aprox TimeStamp
function valueifyDate(date){
    if(typeof date == 'object'){
    return date.getTime();
  }else{
    return new Date(date).getTime();
  } 
}

var bday = document.getElementById('birthday');
bday.addEventListener("change", function(e){
  var today = new Date();
  if(valueifyDate(today) < valueifyDate(e.target.value)){
    console.log("younger than today");
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jbnLx3v3/

Answer (score 0):

To check whether you have date in `startDate` it is better to use [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) (which is implicitly used in `Date` constructor) and compare check if it is not `NaN`. As already mentioned, you need to get numeric value corresponding to the time by using `today.getTime()`. Then you can compare parsed `startDate` and `today.getTime()`. Also it should be `getElementById` not `getElementByID`. Please see corrected code below:

```js
function compareDates() {
  var startDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById('biday').value);
  var today = new Date();
  if (!isNaN(startDate) && startDate > today.getTime()) {
    alert("The first date is after the second date!");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="bday" id="biday" required onchange='compareDates()'>
```

Comment: Using the built-in parser is the worst way to validate a date string if you expect a particular format. Where input type date is supported, the value will be an ISO 8601 formatted string, which has other issues where the built-in parser is used.

Comment: Please provide an example or link to one, to explain why `Date.parser` is not the best choice

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) Or [*read the specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.parse): parsing of any format other than ISO 8601 extended format is implementation dependent. Even parsing of ISO 8601 formatted dates is specified to be inconsistent with the standard that ECMA-262 supposedly supports.